# How to pass attributes to an Ember.View from the template

Tags: ember.js

I have defined the following Ember.View:

```
App.ControlGroup = Ember.View.extend
  classNames: ['control-group']
  layoutName: 'controlGroup'
```

For which the layout template (controlGroup.handlebars) looks like this:

```
<label class="control-label">{{ view.label }}</label>
<div class="controls">
  {{ yield }}
</div>
```

Here is an example that uses the above defined view:

```
  {{#view App.ControlGroup label="Property code"}}
    {{#if isNew}}
      {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="code"}}
    {{else}}
      <p>{{code}}</p>
    {{/if}}
  {{/view}}
```

This will generate the following html:

```
<div id="ember10170" class="ember-view control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Property code</label>
  <div class="controls">   
    <input id="ember10172" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is exactly what I want. However, I learned that using the view's attributes in the template (see `{{ view.label }}` above, in controlGroup.handlebars }}) is an anti-pattern and that property lookup should come from the view's controller. So I wonder how to go about that. In this case, the property pertains to the view (the html snippet) itself so my implementation seems legit to me but I'm curious to see other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using view properties is a bad practice per se, it's just people tend to overuse this capability of Ember. As models, controllers, views has different lifetimes, the "what goes where" question can be broken down to this:

- **Models**: *persistable* data, will survive a page refresh.
- **Controllers**: *non-persistable* data, won't survive a page refresh, but indifferent to view re-renders.
- **Views**: *gets destroyed from time to time*, eg. inside an `{{#if}}` helper.

I think the behavior of these 3 components implies where to put any given property.
(Also, I think your example is perfectly organized, and I'd love to hear the reasoning if I'm wrong about that) :)

Edit: In case of the `label` property, it's pretty much how, for example, the `value` property is implemented in core classes like `Ember.TextField`. It's possible to just give it a value when using the `{{view}}` helper: `{{view Ember.TextField value="foo"}}`), and it's also possible to forward it to the controller by declaring it a binding: `{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="foo"}}`. The latter will use the property named `foo` on the controller.

Comment: Nice way to look at separation of concerns. In what concerns using the view's property in its template I fail to see how it can be abused or what's considered an abuse. As you say, it's also used in the built-in Ember views, e.g in Ember.Select the template contains {{view.prompt}}.

Comment: One such overuse is to declare a `fullName` computed property on the view which concats the model's `firstName` and `lastName` property. It definitely should be declared on the controller. This fits nicely to the separation of concerns: it's a property related to the model, but should not be persisted. Yes, it's technically possible to define `fullName` on the view, but it really doesn't belong there. I think the emphasis on keeping the view free of model-related stuff also comes from the fact that views used to be default targets for property lookups and actions back in the good ol' days.

Comment: This makes total sense. Funny that you mention fullName should be declared on the controller since that is the [canonical example given in the guide for a computed model property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/). The important thing is, I'm now pretty certain I used a view attribute correctly in the template and did not introduce an anti-pattern. Thank you.